# Transaction management in database when two spring boot application trying to access the same record

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Two spring boot applications are connected to the common database.

I just wanted to know, how to handle the transaction if both the application try to update the record at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to use JPA (via Spring Data JPA) there isn't much to handle.

The database itself will prevent two transactions to update the record at the same time. So one will always be first.

If you use optimistic locking (which is the default with JPA) the second transaction will notice the modified row and rollback.

Without that the second transaction will simply overwrite the changes with it's own changes.